# About how to apply commitment discount to different types of instances

Tags: google-compute-engine

HI friends how to correctly apply commitment discount to different types of instances?

I have 4 different servers on one project, in one zone.

n1-standard-1 (1 vCPU, 3.75 GB memory)
custom (2 vCPUs, 9.75 GB memory)
n1-highmem-2 (2 vCPUs, 13 GB memory)
custom (1 vCPU, 3 GB memory)

How i should apply discounts to them. There is 2 custom, 1 high mem and one standart.

Should it be 3 different commitment discounts? I plan to take 3 years commitment and i am not sure if i can take one custom or should i take 3 different?

Answer (score 0):

Before proceeding with the purchase of a [commitment](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/signing-up-committed-use-discounts#purchasecommitment), please check your [quota](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/signing-up-committed-use-discounts#quota) commitments from Google Cloud Platform Console.
Only one purchase is needed if all servers are in the same region. See [restrictions](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/signing-up-committed-use-discounts#restrictions).